# Prove of $\prod_{d|n} (\mu(d)(\mu(d) + 3) + 4) = 4^{d(n)}$

Tags: number-theory, products, mobius-function, multiplicative-function

Found an interesting relation:
$$\prod_{d|n} (\mu(d)(\mu(d) + 3) + 4) = 4^{d(n)}$$
where $\mu(n)$ is a Möbius function and $d(n)$ is a divisors count.

I think this should be something known. The prove I know is a bit tricky and can be found in http://oeis.org/A262804

---

Based on nice answers, just the other formula:

$$\prod_{d|n} \left(\mu(d) \left(\mu(d) \left(\mu(d) + \frac{a(a-1)^2}{2}\right) + \frac{ a^3 - a-2}{2}\right)+ a^2\right) = a^{2d(n)}$$

Comment: Can you share your proof? What's tricky about it?

Comment: My proof was related to the A262804 sequence definition and below formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\begin{align}\mu(d)(\mu(d)+3)+4&=\begin{cases}4&\mu(d)=0\\2&\mu(d)=-1\\8&\mu(d)=1\end{cases}\\&=2^{2+\mu(d)}\end{align}$$

---

Given $m,p$ we have that if $a=\frac{m(p-1)^2}2,b=\frac{m(p^2-1)}2,c=mp ,$ then $$\prod_{d\mid n}\left(a\mu^2(d)+b\mu(d)+c\right)=(mp)^{d(n)}$$

The case $m=p=2$ is your case, and is the only case where $a=1,$ at where $m,p$ are integers.

When $m=1,p=3,$ you get $a=2,b=4,c=3.$

Comment: Yes. With the Calvin Lin answer everything is simple. But how to choose the correct answer?

Comment: Would be interesting to find a similar formula for example for 3, 9, 27.

Comment: Thank you very nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For $n > 1 , \sum_{d\mid n } \mu (d) = 0 $.

Hence, $ \sum_{d\mid n }  ( \mu (d) + 2) = 2 d(n)$.

The result follows.

---

Note that for $n= 1$ the relation isn't true.
In particular, for $ n = 1$, $ \sum_{d\mid n } \mu (d) = 1 $, and in a similar manner we conclude that the RHS $= 2^{ 2 + 1 }$.

Comment: Thank you. With Thomas Andrews answer it is simple. How to choose the correct answer?

Comment: Chose the one that was most helpful to you. Ultimately, we were presenting the same proof, but decided to hint on different parts, so it could be a coin toss as to which part you didn't understand. (I thought Thomas's hint was obvious, and that my hint was the crucial crux to simplify the rest. In addition, it pointed out the edge case that you missed.)

Comment: Thank you, let me choose the first answer.